# Select rows that don't appear in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is the problem: I have table of matches of soccer, every row has one country and id of match, for example:

```
ID1 Russia;
ID1 Egypt
```

Means it was game between Russia and Egypt. But in table I have rows only for teams that scored a goal. For example if it was USA - Canada 2-0 in table I will have:

```
ID2 USA GOALS: 2
```

And I have a table of all games, where it will be row with ID2 Canada but without goals. What I'm trying to do is add to new table rows with zero goals to countries who didn't score, like:

```
ID2 USA GOALS:2;
ID2 CANADA GOALS:0
```

But I'm getting something weird. Here's some screenshots to see:

[image: Columns: Date, Group, Country, Id, Goals. This is table of countries who scored]

[image: Table of all games: Id, Group, Country, Date]

Now I want to check if there is row in first table for ID & Country and if its not, that means country didn't scored and I should add new row with this ID, Country and zero goals. I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```sql
select #AllCountries.Date, #AllCountries.Group, #Country, #Id, 0 as Goals
    from #AllCountries inner join #CountriesWhoScored
    ON #AllCountries.Id = #WhoScored.Id
    WHERE #AllCountries.Id = #WhoScored.Id AND #AllCountries.Country != #WhoScored.Country
```

But I'm getting duplicates of rows which already exists in table with countries who scored:

[image: For example at least one country of 4ID shouldnt be here]

P.S: It's SQL Server 17 and I'm working in SSMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thnk that you just need a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select c.*, coalesce(s.Goals, 0)
from #AllCountries c
left join #CountriesWhoScored s on s.Id = c.Id and s.Country = c.Country
```

For a country that did not score, `s.Goals` ends up `null`: then you can use `coalesce()` to turn it to `0`.

Comment: Thx, I will try it, but what's c.* stands for? And whats 'a' when theres no a up in code?

Comment: `c.*` means: all columns in `c`. `c` is a table alias for `#AllCountries`.